# Why are default values ignored in flask WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I noticed that sometimes my default values are ignored in flask WTForms. For example, the following will sometimes hit an assertion error:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    something = StringField('something', validators=[], default='fun')

# ... do some stuff

def do_stuff():
    example = MyForm()
    assert example.something.data == 'fun'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that flask wtforms will auto-fill your form. Most of the time this is helpful but sometimes if you are having command A make some forms to run command B, this causes problems.

To make sure that your newly instantiated form has the defaults you specified and that flask does *NOT* pull data from the request, you need to explicitly pass `formdata=None` (e.g., replace `MyForm()` with `MyForm(formdata=None)` as described at http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html